# Does postgres allow null values in multi column indexes?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a mutli column index (A,B,C) on a table where C is a nullable column. Will this index store values when C is null? oracle db seems to allow this, but not sure about postgres

Comment: Yes - it is ok.  Primary keys do not accept null values though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, NULL values will be stored in the index and unlike Oracle, this is also true if **all** column values are null.

There is a difference on how Oracle and Postgres handle **unique** indexes with null values though:

The following works in Postgres, but will fail in Oracle

```
create table test (a int, b int, c int);
create unique index on test(a, b, c);
insert into test values (1,1,null);
insert into test values (1,1,null);
```

- [Postgres example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e0bf08135334f9f104b4291c34c73fd9)
- [Oracle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=10b1906b5d7e7d232c187a3b2c068a4b)

---

Edit

Since Postgres 15, this behaviour can be changed in Postgres:

The following index will not allow the above two inserts

```
create unique index on test(a, b, c) nulls not distinct;
```

Comment: Can someone explain the postgres example? looks like a gotcha to me. Oracle behavior is what I expected

Comment: @mhd: `null` is not "equal" to `null` - so two rows with null values in the same column(s) don't evaluate to "equal", so Postgres allows it. Note that both comply with the SQL standard, because this specific corner case is marked as "implementation dependent". Note that since Postgres 15, you can specify how it should behave when creating the index.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL treats `NULL` as `distinct` value, therefore, you can have multiple NULL values in a column with an index.